# Moving a bitmap to the front

Tags: vb.net, image, graphics

So
I need to put an image on a picturebox

I have a form with a panel which contain a picturebox and an image.

I use image because I need to rotate it.
what I get is that the picture cover the image and I need the opposite.
picturebox.sendToBack doesnt work and i cant find img.bringToTop function.

```
Imports System.Drawing.Drawing2D
Public Class Form1

    Dim g As Graphics
   
    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        g = Panel1.CreateGraphics
    End Sub


    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim img As Image
        img = Bitmap.FromFile(Application.StartupPath & "/pic/" & "clay.jpg")
        g.RotateTransform(330)
        g.DrawImage(img, 70, 170, 100, 100)
        Pb.SendToBack()
    End Sub
End Class
```

[ pictures][1]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/s9goC.jpg

Comment: Think about your form and the controls on it as physical object that are layered. If you had a physical panel and then a physical picture box in front of it and then you drew a picture on the panel, would you be surprised that the picture box obscured that drawing? Of course not, because that's exactly what you would expect. You also wouldn't expect to be able to position the picture box between the panel and the drawing on the panel. The obvious thing to do would be to draw on the picture box as well and then, when you line them up, it would look like a single drawing. Do the same here.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of what I linked to in the comments that applies to your specific scenario. This code will draw the same `Image` on a `Panel` and a `PictureBox`. It will work whether the `PictureBox` is a child of the `Panel` or a sibling.

```vb
Private ReadOnly img As Image = Image.FromFile("file path here")

Private Sub DrawImage(c As Control, g As Graphics)
    'The image will be drawn at (100,100) in form coordinates.
    'Translate that location to coordinates for the current control.
    Dim imgLocation = c.PointToClient(Me.PointToScreen(New Point(100, 100)))

    g.DrawImage(img, imgLocation)
End Sub

Private Sub Panel1_Paint(sender As Object, e As PaintEventArgs) Handles Panel1.Paint
    DrawImage(Panel1, e.Graphics)
End Sub

Private Sub PictureBox1_Paint(sender As Object, e As PaintEventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.Paint
    DrawImage(PictureBox1, e.Graphics)
End Sub
```

In that code, there is an individual `Paint` event handler for each control and they both call a common method that does the drawing. If you want to, you can bundle it all into a single common event handler:

```vb
Private ReadOnly img As Image = Image.FromFile("file path here")

Private Sub Controls_Paint(sender As Object, e As PaintEventArgs) Handles Panel1.Paint,
                                                                          PictureBox1.Paint
    'The image will be drawn at (100,100) in form coordinates.
    'Translate that location to coordinates for the current control.
    Dim imgLocation = DirectCast(sender, Control).PointToClient(Me.PointToScreen(New Point(100, 100)))

    e.Graphics.DrawImage(img, imgLocation)
End Sub
```